# "Notice undefined index" for an existing element in $form array

Tags: commerce, forms, theming

Basically This is my Array

```
 array( 
        [product_id] => Array
        ( 
         [#type] => hidden
         [#value] => 39 
        )         
      )
```

and I am trying to get the value which is '39'

```
$cartId = $form['product_id']['#value'];
```

and yes I get the value without any issues, but in my site it gives me a notice saying "Notice: Undefined index: product_id in  ..."

This is my entire code

```
function MyModule_form_alter( &$form, $form_state, $form_id )
{
    $cartId = $form['product_id']['#value'];
    print_r ($form['#value']);
    if ($form_id == 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_'.$cartId)
    { 
        $form['add_to_wishlist']['#weight']= 49;
    }   
}
```

any ideas how to fix this? because I couldn't figure the cause of it as it works well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is called for all forms in your Drupal. `$cartId = $form['product_id']['#value'];` is called outside `if`, so it's also executed on all forms. And most of them does not have `$form['product_id']` defined at all. Move that part inside `if` block.

Comment: Thanks Molot,
You gave me an Idea where I added another if condition to check if it's a commerce form and then added the rest of my code inside it.